# How will my laptop performe in 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, compatibility

hi i just bought this laptop.
and i am considering t install Ubuntu 12.04LTS on it

The Specs is :

- Chipset  AMD A50M Chipset
- Memory   DDR3 1333/1066 MHz SDRAM, 2 x SO-DIMM socket for expansion up
  to 8 GB SDRAM *1
- Display  15.6" 16:9 HD (1366x768) LED Backlight
- Graphic  AMD Radeon® HD 7470M 1GB DDR3 VRAM
- Processor AMD E-450

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will perform fine on Ubuntu 12.04, most likely. You might want to install the proprietary graphics drivers to get the best performance out of it but even with the free ones it should work fine for day to day use.

Comment: cool. it is just a long time since i used ubuntu so i am not up to date with drivers and faq ;)
but when u say to day use. will that mean i can whrite and listen to music same time and maby once in a while see a hd movie 720p?

Comment: And the compabiliti how will thT be?